# Reversing every word in a string

Tags: c, strings, interview-questions

Examples:

```
char test1[] = "               ";
char test2[] = "   hello  z";
char test3[] = "hello world   ";
char test4[] = "x y z ";
```

Results:

```
"               "
"   olleh  z"
"olleh dlrow   "
"x y z "
```

The problem:

> Reverse every world in a string, ignore the spaces.
>
> The following is my code. The basic idea is to scan the string, when
>   finding a word, then reverse it. The complexity of the algorithm is
>   O(n), where n is the length of the string.

Could anyone help me verify it? Is there any better solution?

```
void reverse_word(char* s, char* e)
{
    while(s < e)
    {
        char tmp = *s;
        *s = *e;
        *e = tmp;
        ++s;
        --e;
    }
}

char* word_start_index(char* p)
{
    while((*p != '\0') && (*p == ' '))
    {
        ++p;    
    }

    if(*p == '\0')
        return NULL;
    else
        return p;
}

char* word_end_index(char* p)
{
    while((*p != '\0') && (*p != ' '))
    {
        ++p;
    }

    return p-1;
} 

void reverse_string(char* s)
{
    char* s_w = NULL;
    char* e_w = NULL;
    char* runner = s;

    while(*runner != '\0')
    {
        char* cur_word_s = word_start_index(runner);
        if(cur_word_s == NULL)
            break;
        char* cur_word_e = word_end_index(cur_word_s);
        reverse_word(cur_word_s, cur_word_e);
        runner = cur_word_e+1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd skip the spaces in the main loop, instead of having them in the start index calculations.

Comment: Your functions `word_end_index` and `word_start_index` are effectively rewriting `strcspn` and `strspn`. Checkout the standard library!

Comment: Interview in Boulder much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using C++ is an option for you (which your tags suggest), then you might consider using [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) for swapping the characters. You might also want to use [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) to check for whitespace other than `' '`.

You could also write it all in a single function:

```
void reverse_every_word(char* s)
{
    char* front;
    char* back;
    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        // handle whitespace
        while(*s != '\0' && isspace(*s))
            s++;

        // skip to the end of the current word
        front = s;
        while(*s != '\0' && !isspace(*s))
            s++;

        // reverse
        back = s-1;
        while (front < back)
            std::swap(*front++, *back--);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Comments on code

In C++ code you do not want to be messing with C-Strings. All that memory management makes the code hard to maintain and is difficult to get correct. prefer to use std::string which does all the hard work and lets you concentrate on the algorithm.

```
void reverse_word(char* s, char* e)
```

There are already algorithms for reversing stuff `std::reverse()` and swapping the two values `std::swap()` so there is no need to implement either.

```
    while(s < e)
    {
        char tmp = *s;
        *s = *e;
        *e = tmp;
        ++s;
        --e;
    }
```

Space `' '` is not the only *white space character*. Rather than explicitly testing for a space you should use the standard function for testing if a character is white space `std::is_space()`

```
    while((*p != '\0') && (*p == ' '))
```

#### Comments on Algorithm

There is already a std::reverse() algorithm.
Using this would reduce the complexity of your code to just finding the beginning and end of each word. Since `operator>>` does this automatically it makes the code very trivial:

```
void reverse_string(std::string& paragraph)
{
    std::stringstream pStream(paragraph);
    std::string       word;

    paragraph.clear();
    while(pStream >> word)
    {
        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
        paragraph.append(word);
        paragraph.append(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Loki. For the function reverse_string, does it keep the original white space?

Comment: No. Space is dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Having C++11, we could do,

```
template<class InputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
void reverseSeparate(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    first = std::find_if_not(first,last,pred);
    while(first!=last){
        InputIterator t = std::find_if(first,last,pred);
        std::reverse(first,t);
        first = std::find_if_not(t,last,pred);
    }
}
```

using this, we can (among other things) reverse every word in a string.

```
std::string s = "hi   hello world ";
reverseSeparate(s.begin(),s.end(), [](char c){return c==' ';});
```